# On which Stack Exchange site should I ask question about DNS?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have questions about setting up DNS and redirection from subdomain DNS to specific server, with browser keeping my existing site?

Comment: Serverfault looks like a nice choice.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe - only if you're sys admin though.

Comment: @ChrisF, isn't setting up a DNS service not SysAdmin enough?

Comment: @ToonKrijthe - probably, but the Server Fault crowd are very protective of their site, so you have to be sure.

Comment: It's on topic on ServerFault for sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Server Fault FAQ](https://serverfault.com/faq):

> Frequently Asked Questions
> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Server Fault is for Information Technology Professionals needing expert answers related to managing computer systems in a professional capacity.
>
> If your question is about…
>
> - Server and Business Workstation operating systems, hardware, software and virtualization
> - Enterprise storage, backup, and disaster recovery
> - Network routing, switches, and firewalls
> - Operations, maintenance, and monitoring

DNS should fall in the Network routing category.

Besides, [dns is a tag](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/dns) with 4k entries.